# Java sentinel loop, cleaner or more organized way to do this?

Tags: java, loops, sentinel

I am looking for a more compact way to approach my sentinel loops.  The code I have here works exactly like I intended it to, but I was curious if there is a cleaner or neater way to do this without any extra loops or if statements.  Thanks!

```
public void findSmallLarge()
{
    //declaring variable
    int maxValue = 0;
    int minValue = 0;
    int input = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    String sentinel;

    //Scanner object
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //loop asks user to input integers and will tell the user the minimum and maximum values, after the program quits.
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer, or press Q to quit");
    while (!done && in.hasNextInt())
    {           
        System.out.printf("Please enter an integer, or press Q to quit: ");
        input = in.nextInt();

        // if input is greater than the maxvalue, update the maxvalue.
        if (input > maxValue)
            {
            maxValue = input;
            }

        // if input is less than the minimum value, update the minimum value.
        if (input < minValue)
        {
            minValue = input;
        }

        // if the next input is not an int AND done is false, run the loop until an integer is entered.  If q/Q is entered, quit the program.
        if (!in.hasNextInt() && !done)
        {
        while (!in.hasNextInt() && !done)
        {
            sentinel = in.next();
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid integer, or press Q to quit: ");
            if (sentinel.charAt(0) == 'Q' || sentinel.charAt(0) == 'q')
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("You have quit the program");
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    // Print the updated min and max values
    System.out.println("The Max value is: " + maxValue);
    System.out.println("The Minimum value is: " + minValue);
    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) and [`Math.max(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) to replace your `input > maxValue` and `input < minValue` checks like

```
maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, input);
minValue = Math.min(minValue, input);
```

And you should declare them like

```
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

As for your *sentinel* loop, you could use

```
 if (Character.toUpperCase(sentinel.charAt(0)) == 'Q')
```

and you might also remove the `done` boolean, and use

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Haha, I was curious how to impliment the math method in this, but I am wondering mainly about the sentinel loop I have. Is there a more compact way to write it, or is the way I have it right/sufficient?  For example, using the Boolean AND the `!in.hasNextInt()` together.

Comment: Ahh, very cool, thank you for the input.  I will play around with it and see how they work :)  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact answer of what I was looking for.  The code I posted up above continuously asks the user for input, and when the input is bad (i.e anything other than an integer) it tells the user that their input is wrong, and when the user presses Q or q, the program ends.  I found a more straight forward version of what I was looking for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NovLecture {

public static void main(String[] args) {



Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean done = false;
System.out.println("Please enter an integer or press Q to quit");

// While done is not false, run this loop
while(!done)
{
    // if the next input is an int, do this, other wise continue to else
    if(in.hasNextInt())
    {
        int input = in.nextInt();

    } 
    // If input is anything other than an int, place the input into a string
    else 
    {
        String input =  in.next();

        // and if the input is equal to a q or Q, end the program
        // by setting done to true
        if (input.charAt(0) == 'q' || input.charAt(0) == 'Q')
        {
            done = true;
        } 

        //otherwise tell the user the input is bad and to try again, and flush the input.
        else
        {
                System.out.println("Bad input, please try again");
                in.next();

        }
    }
}
}
```

}